# Problems with socket.io in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I'm using SocketIO (https://cocoapods.org/pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift) in my project as follows:

```swift
import SocketIO

class ChatDetailViewController {

  ...

  let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: Environment.chatWebSocketURL)!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    var socket: SocketIOClient! = nil

  ...


override func viewDidLoad() {
   ...

   self.socket = manager.defaultSocket
   self.setSocketEvents()
   self.socket.connect()

   ...
}

...

@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {

   ...

   self.socket.emit("message", ["senderid": Globals.shared.user!.id!,"message": newMessage.message!,"conversationid": self.conversation])

   ...
}

private func setSocketEvents() {

        self.socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
        }

        self.socket.on("message") {data, ack in
            print("received data: \(data)")
        }
    }
...
}
```

My problem is that `self.socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in print("socket connected")}`gets called and "socket connected" is printed to the console.

But `self.socket.on("message") {data, ack in print("received data: \(data)")}` doesn't get called when the other end emits a "message" event. "received data" is never printed to the console.

I have verified that the "message" event gets fired on the other end - there's existing web application that also connects via socket.io and receives the event.

Also, `socket.emit(...)` seems to fire.

What am I doing wrong?
Why is `self.socket.on("message") {data, ack in print("received data: \(data)")}` not getting executed`

Comment: check server-side, if socket remains connected?

Comment: Checked. Even stayed connected over night on localhost now.

Comment: Did you managed to solve it? I'm having the same issue. Any advice will be appreciated!